# ScrollSpy highlights multiple items visible on viewport how can i make only 1 items close to top window highlight/active

Tags: jquery, html, css

ScrollSpy highlights multiple items in `nav` whos contents are visible on screen, Which is good feature of this script but i also want 1 items to highlight in blue color so that user know this is the active top items close to top of window while also highlighting other visible items in nav with in different color.

https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/qBdJZmE

```
<main>
    <div>
        <h1>Smooth Scrolling Sticky ScrollSpy Navigation</h1>
        <section id="introduction">
            <h2>Introduction</h2>
            <p>…</p>
        </section>
        <section id="request-response">
            <h2>Request &amp; Response</h2>
            <p>…</p>
        </section>
        <section id="authentication">
            <h2>Authentication</h2>
            <p>…</p>
        </section>
        <section id="endpoints">
            <h2>Endpoints</h2>
            <section id="endpoints--root">
                <h3>Root</h3>
                <p>…</p>
            </section>
            <section id="endpoints--cities-overview">
                <h3>Cities Overview</h3>
                <p>…</p>
            </section>
            <section id="endpoints--city-detail">
                <h3>City Detail</h3>
                <p>…</p>
            </section>
            <section id="endpoints--city-config">
                <h3>City Config</h3>
                <p>…</p>
            </section>
            <section id="endpoints--city-spots-overview">
                <h3>City Spots Overview</h3>
                <p>…</p>
            </section>
            <section id="endpoints--city-spot-detail">
                <h3>City Spot Detail</h3>
                <p>…</p>
            </section>
            <section id="endpoints--city-icons-overview">
                <h3>City Icons Overview</h3>
                <p>…</p>
            </section>
            <section id="endpoints--city-icon-detail">
                <h3>City Icon Detail</h3>
                <p>…</p>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="links">
            <h2>Links</h2>
            <p>…</p>
        </section>
        <section id="expanders">
            <h2>Expanders</h2>
            <p>…</p>
        </section>
        <section id="filters">
            <h2>Filters</h2>
            <p>…</p>
        </section>
    </div>
    <nav class="section-nav">
        <ol>
            <li><a href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
            <li><a href="#request-response">Request &amp; Response</a></li>
            <li><a href="#authentication">Authentication</a></li>
            <li><a href="#endpoints">Endpoints</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class=""><a href="#endpoints--root">Root</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#endpoints--cities-overview">Cities Overview</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#endpoints--city-detail">City Detail</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#endpoints--city-config">City Config</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#endpoints--city-spots-overview">City Spots Overview</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#endpoints--city-spot-detail">City Spot Detail</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#endpoints--city-icons-overview">City Icons Overview</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#endpoints--city-icon-detail">City Icon Detail</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#links">Links</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#expanders">Expanders</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#filters">Filters</a></li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
</main>
```

[image]

another one

[image]

Comment: working fine on my end

Comment: check with full screen view you will notice mutiple items active https://codepen.io/KGuide/full/qBdJZmE

Comment: I checked that similar to yours its working fine over there but i didnt find any difference between this and your code https://codepen.io/bramus/full/ExaEqMJ

Comment: i have changed active class color to red so that you will c it highlight 3-4 items on screen depending on your screen, If it just shows 1 items in red then not sure if it working for you or not as i have cross check same code on 3 different browser